# How do I get my reducer to update one property of an object in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example, in props I have an object called 'user' that is set to:

```
user = { id: 1, 
         name: jim, 
         email: jim@gmail.com, 
         entries: 4,
         joined: 07-16-2018
       }
```

I want to have the UPDATE_USER_ENTRIES action dispatch updates only to the  user.entries using the payload

What I have for my current reducer function is this:

```
export const loadUserData = (state = initialStateUser, action = {}) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_USER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                user: { 
                    id: action.payload.id, 
                    name: action.payload.name, 
                    email: action.payload.email, 
                    entries: action.payload.entries, 
                    joined: action.payload.joined 
                }
            });
        case UPDATE_USER_ENTRIES:
            return {...state, **// NEED HELP HERE** };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of writing the return in order to return a new user object with just the entries properties updated? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use spread operator like so:

If your state is like:

```
state = {
     foo: "bar",
     user: {
         id: 1, 
         name: "jim", 
         email: "jim@gmail.com", 
         entries: 4,
         joined: "07-16-2018",
    }
}
```

the code below, spread the state, do not touch `foo`, spread state's `user`, update the `entries` property.

```
case UPDATE_USER_ENTRIES:
    return {...state, user: {...state.user, entries: action.payload } };
```

If your state looks like:

```
user: {
         id: 1, 
         name: "jim", 
         email: "jim@gmail.com", 
         entries: 4,
         joined: "07-16-2018",
    }
```

the above code spreads the state, which is `user` only, then updates the `entries` property.

```
case UPDATE_USER_ENTRIES:
    return {...state, entries: action.payload };
```

Your payload is holding just one value: `userEntries` hence it is only equal to userEntries. So in your reducer you need to use it according to this: `action.payload` Your payload is not an object which holds a `userEntries` value.

Comment: So if my state is holding more than just 'user', should I use the first method?

Comment: I tried the first method and everything returns fine except for entries which returns as undefined. Please help

Comment: I've edited my answer. Actually this should work if your structure something like two of the examples. How is your state structure?

Comment: You are setting your initial state as `initialStateUser,. This is why I thought in the first place that you are holding just the user in this reducer state.

Comment: Ah yeah the initialStateUser was just the initial values for 'user'. I still can't get state to update correctly using your first method. The payload is correct by my console.log() checks but the entries property in the user object keeps going to undefined. I'm not sure how to debug this further

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your payload is equal to userEntries, it is not an object which holds userEntries. I've also explained this in my answer's last paragraph. Here is a simple working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkwl2w8zlm